# WordPress if post.php but only for one Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, custom-post-type

This is for the back end. The admin area. I have a script to run some functions but only for the Events custom post type created by the Events Calendar. Currently I have this script running in my functions.php:

```
if ($page == "post-new.php" OR $page == "post.php" ) {
    do something.....;
}
```

So it works, but on anything with post-new.php or post.php. Not good since this involves fields only related to the Events CPT. How can I get it to work exclusively on this CPT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you can rely on the [`get_current_screen()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) function to return the data of what admin page you're on:

```
$current_screen = get_current_screen();

if( $current_screen->base == 'post' && $current_screen->post_type == 'your-post-type-here' ){
    // Do things
}
```

There's also the `$post_type` [Global Variable](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables) but honestly, I don't see it used too much.